# Как вывести все комментарии, содержащийся в исходном коде?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Как написать программу, которая читает файл с исходным кодом Java и выводит все комментарии, содержащийся в файле? Можно ли это сделать при помощи регулярных выражений?

Comment: "У меня была одна проблема и я решил решать её регуляркой. Теперь у меня две проблемы"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это не сложно сделать при помощи регулярных выражений. 
Достаточно учесть, что может встретиться текст. Вроде в Java больше нет способных повлиять синтаксических конструкций.

```
"(?:\\.|[^"])+"      |
(\/\/[^\n]*)(?=\n|$) |
(\/\*.*?\*\/)
```

Это многострочное регулярное выражение выполняющее поставленную задачу. Признаком комментария служит наличие текста в первой или второй сохраняющей группе.

https://regex101.com/r/gR7sP3/1

Answer (score 4):

Это затруднительно сделать с помощью регулярных выражений.

Вам нужно распарсить весь текст исходников, с учетом разных типов комментарий, их вхождения в строки. Учесть вложенные комментарии и вложенные строки.

Простое решение - найти и использовать готовый парсер, уверен для Java их много разных.

Comment: Это можно сделать при помощи регулярных выражений

Comment: @ReinRaus согласен, подправил ответ

Answer (score 2):

В общих чертах комменты:

- начинаются с `//`
- начинаются  с `/*` и заканчиваются `*/`

При этом во втором случае коммент обычно многострочный.

Также эти символы могут встречаться в строках.
А ещё есть Java-doc комменты.

В общем это нетривиальная задача.