# Вывести все комментарии из cpp файла в out.txt

Tags: linux, bash

Друзья! Только начинаю изучать принцип с bash и столкнулся с одной неприятной проблемой. Нужно найти все комментарии(в том числе и многострочные) в заданном .cpp файле(проверить расширение файла) и вывести их в заданный выходной файл. Не получается нормально выделить комментарии

```
    #!/bin/bash
name1=$1 #solution.cpp
name2=$2 #out.txt
if [ ${name1: -4} == ".cpp" ]; then
    cat solution.cpp | grep ^\//
else
    echo "bad"
fi
```

Comment: 1. [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/517021/178576) 2. ну и по древней закрепившейся традиции у вопроса, не имеющего ни малейшего отношения к программе bash, ставится метка bash. это нормально. 3. да, и к программе linux, тоже традиционно, вопрос не имеет ни малейшего отношения. это вообще классика.